# Change value of all strings in column based on condition

Tags: r, data-cleaning

New-ish to R, I have a question about data cleaning.

I have a column that contains what type of drive a car is - four wheel, all wheel, 2 wheel etc

The problem is there is no standardization, so some rows have 4 WHEEL drive, 4wd, 4WD, Four - Wheel - Drive, etc

The first step is easy, which is to uppercase everything but the step I'm having trouble with is changing each value to a standard, like 4WD, without having to recode each unique drive.

Something like For Each value in column, if value LIKE/CONTAINS "FOUR" change to "4WD".

I've researched recode and stringdist and mutate but I can't find a fit. When I typed it out it sounds like I need a loop but not sure the exact syntax.

If the solution could work with the tidyverse that would be great!

Comment: Would suggest looking at `match()` to help with this.

Comment: @RobJensen that looks good. Really need something that does LIKE/CONTAINS and that seems like thats what it does. I'll try that one

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've answered your question, but in the future, please include a small sample of your data so it's easier for us to solve your problem.  Food for thought: [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)


# Since you haven't provided a data sample, I'm going to assume your dataframe is named "DF" and your column's name is "Drive"

# Set everything to lowercase to pare down uniqueness
DF <- mutate(DF, Drive = replace(Drive, Drive, tolower(Drive)))


# You'll need one line like this for each replacement.  Of the following form:
#     <column_name> = replace(<column_name>, <condition>, <new value>)
DF <- mutate(DF, Drive = replace(Drive, Drive == "4 wheel drive", "4WD"))
```

Comment: In this column there are ~45 unique values so doing that for each is tiresome and with how the file is created, there could be different variations that aren't captured. Want to stay away from hard-coding it, that's why I wanted it to have LIKE/CONTAINS functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` and `grepl`. Change the first argument of `grepl` to something that will match all your desired cases. Below searches for strings containing "4" or "FOUR"

```
df$cleaned_col <- ifelse(grepl('4|four', df$colname_here, ignore.case = T), '4WD', df$colname_here)
```

If you want to do multiple comparisons you may want to use `dplyr::case_when` with `%like%` from `data.table`

```
require(dplyr);require(data.table)
df %>% mutate(cleaned = case_when(colname %like% 'a|b' ~ "there's an a or b in there"
                                  , colname %like% 'c' ~ "has a c in it"
                                  , T ~ "no a or b or c"))
```

Comment: Does `dplyr` part add anything? You main functions are `ifelse` and `grepl`, that's all you need. Also, you can add `all` to patterns.

Comment: @RobJensen If I wanted to do multiple arguments, so '4 | FOUR' = "4WD", 'All Wheel | A' = "AWD" 

How would I do that?

Comment: @RobJensen that's perfect. Exactly what I needed. I had tried case_when but I didn't have %like%. Thanks so much! Many cleaning to do :-)